# Typescript Angular, how do I call - as part of a chain of Observables - an operation on each member of an array and just return a count of successes?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, fork-join

I have a parent record I need to create, and then a series of child records to create (order not important). Then I need to do a follow-up logging action.

I know how to create a chain of single actions on an observable by mapping them together, so, I could do:

-- create one parent record, return its id:

`createParentRecord(parentInfo: parentType): Observable<number>`

-- create one child record, return its id

`createChildRecord(childInfo: childType): Observable<number>`

-- log the entry

`logStuff(parentId: number, childId: number)`

-- composite function does all the work, returning the parentId

```
doTheThing(): Observable<number> {
   /* ... */
   let parentId: number;
   let childId: number;

   return createParent(parentInfo).pipe(
     tap(id => (parentId = id)),
     mergeMap(id => { childInfo.parentId = parentId; return createChildRecord(childInfo);} ),
     mergeMap(childId => { childInfo.childId = childId; return logStuff(parentId, childId); ),
     map( () => parentId)
   ); 
}
```

## Question

This works great.

BUT if I have childInfo[] rather than childInfo, how do I do this?
how do I handle an array of childInfo[] to subscribe to and return inner observable results?
I just want a number back of how many succeeded - or just whatever results come back from each observable?
Do I use forkJoin()?

I can't for the life of me figure this out. Help?

Comment: Is childInfo already initialized before running the observable stream? I do not See it in your Code snippet. Looks like you actually want to pass childId as parameter to `createChildRecord(childInfo)`

Comment: Yes, we have the child record info all ready to go, just need the parent record to get created to get its id so we can create it linked to its parent.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right your question, I would proceed like this. Comments are inline

```
function doTheThing(): Observable<any> {
   /* ... */
   let parentId: number;
   // somehow there is an array of children info to be saved
   const childInfos = new Array(3).fill({})

   return createParent('Parent Info').pipe(
     tap(id => (parentId = id)),
     concatMap(id => { 
         // each childInfo is filled with the result of the createParent operation
         childInfos.forEach(c => c.parentId = parentId); 
         // an array of Observable is created - each one represents a createChildRecord operation
         const childInfosObs = childInfos.map(ci => createChildRecord(ci))
         // all child record operations are executed in parallel via forkJoin
         return forkJoin(childInfosObs);
      }),
     concatMap(childIds => { 
       // forkJoin returns an array of results with the same order as the array of Observables passed to forkJoin
       // therefore we can loop through the array and set each childInfo with its result
       childInfos.forEach((ci, i) => ci.childId = childIds[i])
       // last thing we do is to log and then return the results of the forkJoin
       return logStuff(parentId, childIds).pipe(
         map(() => childIds)
       );
     } )
   ); 
}
```

Note that I use `concatMap` instead of `mergeMap`. Unless there is a specific reason, anytime I do DB or Rest operations I prefer `concatMap` just to keep the sequence of operations.

You can also enrich every observable contained in `childInfosObs` with some error handling logic if required, considering that `forkJoin` would error if any of the Observables it tries to execute errors.

[Here a stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ojkd5p?file=index.ts) with an example of the proposed solution.

Comment: hot damn, it totally worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote

You could map your `ChildInfo[]` to an observable array and then merge it like this:

```
return createParent(parentInfo).pipe(
  tap(newParentId => parentId = newParentId),
  mergeMap(newParentId => forkJoin(
   childInfos.map(childInfo => { // this is an Array map.
     childInfo.parentId = parentId;
     return createChildRecord(childInfo); // this should return childInfo, since it sounds like a CRUD operation.
   })
  )),
```

Note that this only works if`createChildRecord` completes because `forkJoin` won't emit otherwise. I assumed this was a single call in my solution.
If you make `createChildRecord` return the updated version of your childInfo, your life should become much easier in the following operations as well.

```
createChildRecord(childInfo: ChildInfo): Observable<ChildInfo> {

  const childId = /** TBD **/
  return of({...childInfo, childId});
}
```

For readability, consider putting the inner observable in some kind of method.

Comment: Love the suggestion of doing the forkJoin in another routine - it's how the code is actually setup right now, I was just trying to simplify for the example. :)